# pandas - multiple columns to "column name - value" columns

Tags: python, pandas, stack, multiple-columns, reshape

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns and I want to "flatten" it to just two columns - one with column name and the other with values. E.g.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],'B':[2,3], 'C':[3,4]})
```

How can I convert it to look like:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'column name': ['A','A','B','B','C','C'], 'value': [1,2,2,3,3,4]})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `stack` to stack all column values into a single, column, then drop the first level index calling `reset_index`, overwrite the column names with the ones you desire and then finally sort using `sort_values`:

```
In [37]:
df2 = df1.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
df2.columns = ['column name', 'value']
df2.sort_values(['column name', 'value'], inplace=True)
df2

Out[37]:
  column name  value
0           A      1
3           A      2
1           B      2
4           B      3
2           C      3
5           C      4
```

Comment: Hmmm, 2 minutes difference ... What do you think?

Comment: @jezrael your first posted answer was incorrect and incomplete hence why I posted mine, it matters little in the big scheme of things

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to `MultiIndex` `Series` and then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df2 = df1.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index().sort_values('index')
df2.columns = ['column name','value']
print (df2)
  column name  value
0           A      1
3           A      2
1           B      2
4           B      3
2           C      3
5           C      4
```

One row solution with `rename` column `index` to `column name`:

```
df2 = df1.stack()
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         .reset_index(name='value')
         .sort_values(['index'])
         .rename(columns={'index':'column name'})
print (df2)
  column name  value
0           A      1
3           A      2
1           B      2
4           B      3
2           C      3
5           C      4
```

If need sort by both columns:

```
df2 = df1.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index().sort_values(['index',0])
df2.columns = ['column name','value']
print (df2)
  column name  value
0           A      1
3           A      2
1           B      2
4           B      3
2           C      3
5           C      4
```